# Type safe URL Action in MVC3 issue

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I don't like Url.Action("string", "string) and hence wrote below extension method

```
public static string Action<TController>(this UrlHelper urlHelper, Expression<Func<TController, object>> actionExpression)
{
    var controllerName = typeof(TController).GetControllerName();
    var actionName = actionExpression.GetActionName();

    return urlHelper.Action(actionName, controllerName);
}
```

I use it in my razor view like below:

```
@{Url.Action<ClientController>(action => action.ClientDetails());}
```

It doesn't render anything. Am I making any mistake anywhere or am I missing anything? Is it possible to do this as I like the Type Safe nature, rather than hard-coding actionnames and controllers?

Comment: Have you had a look at MvcContrib? this kind of stuff is already implemented (several times before)

Comment: System.Type does not have a method called GetControllerName. Your' code either won't compile or the question would benefit from the implementation of the implementation (if it is such), same of course goes for getActionName

Comment: I implemented an extension method on Type for GetControllerName() and I already compiled the project to the point where I am. I am just not sure how to use it in razor view

Comment: yes but the code you have does not work as you intended and the above code looks a'ok so the bug is in one of the two extension methods and not in the code you've posted always post a short selfcontained correct and complete exmaple (see http://sscce.org)

Answer (score 1):

Using the brackets denotes a code block. Using the parenthesis (seen below) is an explicit expression. The expression will output as part of the HTML, but the code block will not.

```
@(Url.Action<ClientController>(action => action.ClientDetails()))
```

[Check out this SO post for a more complete answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756139/difference-between-parenthesis-and-curly-brackets-in-razor)