# Render PartialView into section

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I've got a section `Left` that contains navigation content for my specific page.

Now I want to display a TreeView in that, thus I created a partial view to pass a specific model to that view. Now I'm trying to render that specific view into my section - but the section stays empty.

This does not work:

```
@section Left {
    @Html.Partial("PartialNavigationView")
}
```

And rendering the thing returns an error `Expression must return a value to render`:

```
@section Left {
    @Html.RenderPartial("PartialNavigationView")
}
```

How can I render a partial view into my section?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6980823/html-renderpartial-syntax-with-razor

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Try

`@{Html.RenderPartial("PartialNavigationView");}`

or

`@{Html.Partial("PartialNavigationView");}`

should work also.

Comment: Ah, alright,  this does work. Thank you - I'll accept the answer when I can in 11 minutes! :)

Comment: @rar This might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756139/difference-between-parenthesis-and-curly-brackets-in-razor

Comment: @span Cheers for adding that link. I already posted the link in a comment above, but it's not obvious, so posting it here is a good idea.