# What is the syntax for a strongly-typed ActionLink in MVC 4 with MVC 4 Futures?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2, asp.net-mvc-futures

I am using a new MVC 4 Internet application template with Visual Studio 2012.  I have installed the Nuget package for MVC 4 Futures.  In my `_Layout.cshtml` I am building the navigation menu.

This works and builds the correct URL:

> @Html.ActionLink("Customers", "Index", "Customers")

This is what I would like to work, a strongly-typed variation:

```
@Html.ActionLink<CustomersController>(c => c.Index(), "Customers", null)
```

It griefs on "Cannot choose method from method group. Did you mean to invoke a method?", but something tells me that's not the real issue.

This compiles and outputs the right HTML, but not inline:

```
@{
   var t = Html.ActionLink<CustomersController>(c => c.Index(), "Customers");
   Response.Write(t);
}
```

How do you build strongly-typed Action/ActionLink's in MVC 4 using Razor's syntax (with or without Futures)?

Comment: I read many books about asp.net mvc, but never saw strongly type action link, thanks for good question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
@(Html.ActionLink<CustomersController>(x => x.Index(), "Customers"))
```

[The Basics – (Strongly-Typed) Linking to MVC Actions](http://trycatchfail.com/blog/post/ASPNET-MVC-3-Razor-C-and-VBNET-WebForms-ActionLink-RenderPartial-and-RenderAction-in-WebForms.aspx)

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756139/difference-between-parenthesis-and-curly-brackets-in-razor) covers it loosely.

Comment: does this syntax still exist in MVC , I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Should mention one needs to add references to `Microsoft.Web.Mvc` and to their controllers (`MyWebApp.Controllers`)

Comment: Does this option still exist in more recent .NET frameworks?